# Pandas If/Truth Statements Value error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare the results of 2 values, but i'm not sure what is happening here.

```
# Read items into Dataframe and count the number of rows there is. 
df_csv = pandas.read_csv('dataset.csv', index_col=False, header=None)
print(len(df_csv.index))

# Creating Session to count the number of rows there are in the SQL file
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
# Getting count
meta = MetaData()
table_to_count = Table('Database count details', meta, autoload=True, 
                        autoload_with=engine)
df_sql = session.query(func.count(table_to_count)).scalar()
print(df_sql)

# Perform logic test
if df_csv <= df_sql:
print("sql is less than csv")

elif df_csv >= df_sql:
print("CSV is current with sql")
```

However, the error I am getting is `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I referred to some other questions on stackoverflow, but i'm still not able to solve this. What do you think?

**Edit**

`print(len(df_csv.index))` will return the value `3984`.

`print(df_sql)` will return `3982`

So i'm trying to compare these 2 numbers.

Comment: `if` doesn't understand boolean operations on arrays because like the error states if you have 1 or all positive conditions in your array so you need to decide if you're looking for 1 or more positive matches, e.g. `if (df_csv <= df_sql).all():` etc..

Comment: What do you expect `df_csv <= df_sql` to mean?

Comment: @Goyo I've edited my question. Hope it helps?

Comment: So you want to compare `len(df_csv.index)` with `df_sql` (which, if I understand correctly, you've called `df_sql` even though it's not a dataframe but just a number), but instead of comparing `len(df_csv.index)` and `df_sql`, you're comparing `df_csv` with `df_sql`?

Comment: @jakewong "So i'm trying to compare these 2 numbers." You don't know how to compare 2 numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `len`:

```
if len(df_csv) <= df_sql:
    print("sql is less than csv")
elif len(df_csv) >= df_sql:
    print("CSV is current with sql")
```

But I think you need:

```
if len(df_csv) > df_sql:
    print("sql is less than csv")
elif len(df_csv) == df_sql:
    print("CSV is current with sql")
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this answers my question. I tried your method, but i'm still not able to get the logic test to work

Comment: This returns me an error message `object of type 'int' has no len()`

Comment: Sorry, I think it was typo.